# "Subreddit" style URL routing in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Reddit links are normally like this:

`https://www.reddit.com/r/<subreddit>/<topic>`

meaning that, the subreddit can be anything depending on how the user created it.

Usually on ASP MVC, We can do it like this:

`local/controller/action?subreddit=subname&topic=topicname`

but what if I want it to be something like this:

`local/controller/action/subname/topicname` ?

Comment: Create a route definition for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword for this feature is attribute routing in ASP.NET MVC. There is a lot of information availbale in blogs etc.

With the `Route`-Annotation you can decorate your action and define a mapping between URL parts and parameters for the action call.

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    [Route("r/{subreddit}/{topic}")]
    public ActionResult Topic(string subreddit, string topic)
    {
         //Logic goes here
    } 
}
```

Furthermore the attribute routing has to be activted in the `RouteConfig.cs` with `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` like

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can call the `Topic`-Action of the `ExampleController` by `http://localhost:PORT/r/reddit/topic`.

Comment: This would work equally well with global declarative routing, e.g. a route setup for `local/controller/action/subname/topicname`.

Comment: How do I access the URL based from your example?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta: Please try `http://localhost:PORT/r/reddit/topic`

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta: I expanded the answer in order to explain the activation of attribute routing and the request uri.